# Wordpress home page stuck

Tags: wordpress, caching, wordpress-theming

My wordpress's home page stuck on a specific state.
If i change the static home page or modify something it doesn'n applies.
I disabled all the plugins changed the theme to default.
The server side chache is disabled.
Browser cache is disabled.

And still the homepage looks the same.
All the other pages are changing but the home page is stuck.

Also the logged in toolbar is not showing on the homepage.